# Adding rows to Strong Typed Dataset with relation

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

Hello got typed Dataset named DSMain.

Tables

> User:
>             U_id int 
>             U_fname string
>             U_lname string          U_Case int
>
> Case:
>         C_id int        C_date string           C_status int

U_Case is in relation with C_Status,

I want to add data to this table.

> public static void
>   AddNewDluznik(string fname, string
>   lname, int case)
>           {
>               MainData.User.AddUserRow(fname, lname,
>   case);
>           }

Without rel it works.

Argument '3': cannot convert from 'int' to 'Zefir.DSMain.CaseRow'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it, `AddUserRow` has the following signature:

```
AddUserRow(string fName, string lName, CaseRow case) //note case is of type CaseRow, not int.
```

You need to reference the `CaseRow` in your `Case` table to which your user is referencing:

```
public static void AddNewDluznik(string fName, string lName, int case)
{
    MainData.User.AddUserRow(fName, lName, MainData.Case.FindByC_id(case));
}
```

Alternatively, if you are working with isolated tables, and not the whole DataSet you can:

```
public static void AddNewDluznik(string fName, string lName, int case)
{
     var row = MainData.User.NewUserRow();
     row.U_fname = fName;
     row.U_lname = lName;
     row.U_Case = case; 
     MainData.User.AddUserRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using it, Case is an entity, not an int, so you need to get the case to which your user is referencing and add IT as the parameter in your AddUserRow call.

```
Case myCase = <find the case in question>;
MainData.User.AddUserRow(fname, lname, myCase);
```